# Podcast sounds ok on PC but cut out in mobile

Tags: mixing, sound-editing, pc, production-audio, mobile-phone

I have a question regarding podcast making. We use either Audacity or Audition to edit. We distribute on Anchor-Spotify. We have had a situation with two episodes where some parts of the podcast are inaudible when we listen on a mobile device (phone) but when we listen to the exact same track, via the same platform on a PC the episode is complete and you can hear everything as we edited.

Anyone has an idea why and how to fix it ?

Thanx !!!

Answer (score 2):

A total guess, but perhaps there is a section where the phase of one of the stereo channels has been inverted. On a PC with stereo speakers, you may not notice.  But perhaps the mobile is combining the stereo channels to mono in which case they would cancel out.

You could test this theory out by converting to mono in Audacity to see how it sounds.